# Reference data from function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have those info on my haskell code:

```
data Symtable a = General a | Stack a

class Evaluable e where
eval :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Ident -> Maybe a) -> (e a) -> (Either String a)
typeCheck :: (Ident -> String) -> (e a) -> Bool

instance (Num a, Ord a) => Evaluable (NExpr a) where
eval f f2 = Left ("Undefined variable: ") --to make the code compilable
typeCheck f f2 = True --to make the code compilable
```

The thing is, eval function returns the evaluation of a numeric expression (for example 3 + 5, or x + 3), therefore I have to check the value of X on the symtable data but I haven't got it referenced on this function (I cannot edit the function header). How can I do it?

ident = string and Nexpr:

```
data NExpr n = Const n |
            Var Ident |
            Plus (NExpr n) (NExpr n) |
            Minus (NExpr n) (NExpr n) |
            Times (NExpr n) (NExpr n)
```

Comment: Presumably, the first argument to `eval` is the function that does name lookups for any names found in the second argument?

Comment: probably but I'm a bit lost with haskell, I don't know what to do with it or how to pass it or how to evaluate it with those maybe's

Comment: That depends on what `Ident` is and what `NExpr` looks like.

Comment: ident = string, NExpr (updating)

Comment: What do `General a` and `Stack a` constructors mean?

Comment: I don't know, I just made it up, it is supposed to store variables + stack values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first arugment to `eval` is a function that will look up the value of a name found in an expression. You ignore it when evaluating a `Const` value, use it when evaluating a `Var` value, and just pass it along to the recursive calls for the other cases.

```
instance (Num a, Ord a) => Evaluable (NExpr a) where
  eval _ (Const n) = Right n
  eval lookup (Var x) = case lookup x of
                          Nothing -> Left ("Undefined variable: " ++ x)
                          Just y -> Right y

  eval lookup (Plus left right) = (+) <$> eval lookup left <*> eval lookup right
  -- etc
```

Comment: This also requires some changes to the `class Evaluable`, otherwise it involves `NExpr a b` which is a kind error.

Comment: it says: couldn't match type 'e' with NExpr' 'e' is a rigid type variable bound by ... eval::... expected e a actual Nexpr a