# what are <$> and <*> operands in haskell

Tags: haskell, operators

what are those operators in haskell?  and <*>
I have them in a line like this:

```
class Evaluable e where
    eval :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Ident -> Maybe a) -> (e a) -> (Either String a)
    typeCheck :: (Ident -> String) -> (e a) -> Bool

instance Evaluable NExpr where
    eval lookup (Plus left right) = (+) <$> eval lookup left <*> eval lookup right
```

Comment: You should look them up on Hoogle or Hayoo.

Comment: I don't know how to search them

Comment: Well, start by finding them with Google. Once you've done so, type the operator you want into the search field.

Comment: @dfeuer you mean Hoogle?

Comment: it would be maybe easier if you answered the question instead?

Comment: I looked them in hoogle but still don't understand what are they doing on my code

Comment: @Jean-BaptistePotonnier, no, I meant Google to find Hoogle and Hayoo. Daniel, you need to read about applicative functors. Learn You a Haskell has a good explanation.

Comment: Also typeclassopedia is a good reference

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280585/need-to-know-what-and-do-in-haskell (I've found this link with [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am the one who [showed you these operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979668/1126841), I'll give a brief explanation as to why I used them.

---

To review, a functor is a type constructor that lets you use the `fmap` function to apply a function to a "wrapped" value. In the specific case of the `Either` type constructor (partially applied, in this case, to `String`), you can apply a function to a `Right` value, but ignore the function if applied to a `Left` value (your error). It provides a way of error propagation without having to check for the error.

```
fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
fmap f (Left y) = Left y
```

---

An applicative functor is similar, except the function itself can be wrapped just like the argument it is applied to. The `<*>` operator unwraps both its operands, unlike `fmap` which only unwraps its right operand.

```
Right f <*> Right x = Right (f x)
Left f <*> _ = Left f
_ <*> Left y = Left y
```

Typically, you don't wrap functions yourself: they result from using `fmap` to partially apply a function to a wrapped value:

```
fmap (+) (Right 3) == Right (+ 3)
fmap (+) (Left "error") == Left "error"
```

So, when we are working with `Either` values, the use of `<$>` (infix `fmap`) and `<*>` let us pretend we are working with regular values, without worrying about whether they are wrapped with `Left` or `Right`. `Right` values provide the expected `Right`-wrapped answer, and `Left` values are preserved. In the case of a binary operator, only the first `Left` value is returned, but that is often sufficient.

```
(+) <$> Left "x undefined" <*> Left "y undefined" == Left "x undefined" <*> Left "y undefined"
                                                  == Left "x undefined"

(+) <$> Left "x undefined" <*> Right 9 == Left "x undefined" <*> Right 9
                                       == Left "x undefined"

(+) <$> Right 3 <*> Left "y undefined" == Right (+ 3) <*> Left "y undefined"
                                       == Left "y undefined"

(+) <$> Right 3 <*> Right 9 == Right (+3) <*> Right 9
                            == Right 12
```

---

In the end, using the `Applicative` instance of `Either String` lets us combine the results of evaluating two subexpressions without having to explicitly check if either recursive call of `eval` actually succeeded. Successful recursive calls result in success; an error in either call is used as the same error for the top-level call.

Answer (score 3):

The `<$>` operator is an infix form of `fmap`. It allows you to apply a pure function to the value wrapped into some parametric type that belongs to a `Functor` class. The type of `<$>` is `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

The `<*>` operator is quite similar to `<$>`. It allows you to apply a function wrapped into a parametric type to a value wrapped into the same parametric type. The type of `<*>` is `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it's a way to combine the results of `eval`. 
If one part of the the expression is failing, then the whole expression is failing.

This way, its possible to separate error handling of your application logic and to avoid complex nested `case ... of`.

To fully understand this, I'll advise do read on functors first, then applicative functors.

In parallel you can play with Maybe and Either, and write the equivalent code using `case` expressions.